# Add space within the product price in opencart 3.0

Tags: opencart

How to add space into product price? Currency is UZS (Uzbekistan sums).

- Now it's showing            23785000 UZS.
- I want it is showed as 23 785 000    UZS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in the language file, for the default language (en-gb), it's defined here:

```
catalog\language\en-gb\en-gb.php

$_['decimal_point']         = '.';
```

Find above code in your language file and change it:

```
$_['decimal_point']         = ' ';
```

Comment: What I wanted was $_['thousand_point'] = " "; Thank You, anyway!